# how to find hidden endpoints on a site

Tags: rest, python-requests, fiddler

im trying to find a away to go to this site https://www.deadstock.ca, and monitor on the backend for when the upload early the products early

hello, im trying to find a away to go to this site https://www.deadstock.ca, and monitor on the backend for when the upload the products early, doing so i would need to find a hidden endpoint or api, after researching it turns out the best way of doing this is by using fiddler to find all the requests sent, and look for it, chrome dev tools wont work because it doesn't show all the requests, but yea after using fiddler, I still can't find the hidden endpoint, So what should I do,

im expecting to learn what im doing wrong, and learn how to find hidden endpoints on a site

Comment: What exactly are you trying to ask here? Please modify your question so we will know what kind of endpoints are you looking for. You shouldn't try to find hidden endpoints, as they are probably hidden for a reason.

Comment: People find endpoints for Shopify stores that display the products before they are loaded, I’m looking for that endpoint to make a page monitor,

Comment: Hidden pages are hidden because there is no link on the page to them. Therefore you need to look at URLs, identify the pattern and then guess a new URL based on that pattern. A counter in the URL would be such an example: https://example.org/article12345 by incrementing the number you may find a hidden article not yet published.